# Does eclipse support smooth mouse scroll?

Tags: eclipse, mouse

Could I scroll the mouse smoothly just like what I do in sublime? When I scroll fast, the screen scrolls fast.

Note that I know scrolling the mouse with `Ctrl` key pressed, but that's not what I want.